# cannot connect to gitlab locally / browser (Virtual Box linux works just fine)

Tags: linux, git, ssh, windows-10, gitlab

So I've had this problem before at work, then it was solved by getting a new computer (it was old).

Yesterday everything worked fine, this morning I try to surf to the company gitlab and couldn't connect. When I try to clone a repository to my local system I get a port 22: Connection timed out and when I try it with https I get port 443: Timed out

On chrome I get `"ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"`

Edge tells me `"There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"`

I've pinged the ip and I get "Request timed out"

When I run  `$ ssh -vT git@github.com` it gives me a bunch of lines but it ends in

```
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I run `$ ssh -vT git@gitlab.company.com` I just get

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.company.com [10.1.10.21] port 22.
cddebug1: connect to address 10.1.10.21 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gitlab.company.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've regenerated SSH keys and put them in https://gitlab.com/profile/keys (that I can acces, its just the gitlab.company.com that doesn't work).

I talked to IT at the company and they said nothing has changed, no new firewalls, no nothing.

I did install the Chrome Test Server to start making PWA but removed it after I discovered I had this gitlab problem again thinking it might have to do something with it. I rebooted my pc after the uninstall.

What more can I do? I'm on Windows 10 and run Ubuntu in Oracle VM virtual box (where I can connect just fine).

Thanks.

EDIT:
I've done a system restore to a couple of days ago, didn't help, I logged in a different windows account, still couldn't connect, I've changed network cable (using a coworker his "internet") still doesn't work. There must be something that I'm doing locally that messed things up.